# SQL Server : getting the max and min of a sum aggregate

Tags: sql-server, sum, max, aggregate, min

I have a list of orders for products with a `ProductID` and the quantity ordered.

For example:

```
ProductID Quantity
------------------
 1         5
 2         2
 3         5
 1         2
 3         4
 2         8
```

How do I get only the ProductID of the product which sold the most and least in SQL SERVER. I tried:

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS Total
FROM [Order Details]
GROUP BY ProductID
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Now need only the max and min of Total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a common table expression or a derived table to get the `sum`, and then query for `min` and `max`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ProductID, sum(Quantity) as Total
    FROM [Order Details]
    GROUP BY ProductID
)

SELECT MIN(Total) As Lowest, MAX(Total) AS highest
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here, twice:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS Total,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Quantity)) rn_least,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC) rn_greatest
    FROM [Order Details]
    GROUP BY ProductID
)

SELECT
    ProductID,
    CASE WHEN rn_least = 1
         THEN 'least' ELSE 'GREATEST' END AS label,
    Total
FROM cte
WHERE
    rn_least = 1 OR rn_greatest = 1
ORDER BY
    Total;
```